# HAProxy authentication for a specific path

Tags: haproxy

I need to specify a path which, when hit, requires authentication. I've new to HAProxy and have been struggling with this for a while. Here is one attempt:

```
   acl auth_ok http_auth(site_users)  
     http-request path_beg /foo/bar auth realm foo if !auth_ok
```

I've created a user list called auth users, and got auth to work for the entire site. But, if someone hits say, /foo/bar they should be required to authenticate. Not other paths.

Any help is greatly appreciated!